# Gem available in irb but not rails console

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

I am trying to use the RedCloth gem in my rails project. When I used `irb` I can load the gem:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'RedCloth'
```

and it works fine, but when I try the same thing in the rails console I get an error message stating that the gem cannot be found.

Does anyone have any idea what might cause this?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Does your rails project's `Gemfile` include `gem 'RedCloth'` in it? Rails will only load the gems specified in that file.

Comment: Goodness me - that was silly of me. This is obviously new in the current version of rails (Rails 3?) - it definitely wasn't like this last time I worked with rails.

Comment: Specifically, it's a bundler thing, which Rails 3 uses.

Answer (score 26):

You can append gem path to ruby load path. Do this:

```
gem which faker
=> /usr/local/ruby/......../faker-0.1.1/lib/faker.rb
```

Start Rails console and do the following:

```
$: << '/usr/local/ruby/......../faker-0.1.1/lib/'
```

and now load faker gem

```
require 'faker'
=> true
```

Comment: Nice hack.Thanks for sharing.

Comment: Nice workaround. Just so I understand better, is there a reason you can't be defualt require ANY gem that's already in your gemset/gem directory within `rails console`?

Comment: `$:` represents the load path for Rails which it gets from the Gemfile.  It is the same as the `$LOAD_PATH` global.  So this technique puts the new path that we desire into the load path array as its last element.

Comment: rails 6: `require 'faker'` returns false, `require '/usr/local/ruby/......../faker-0.1.1/lib/'` => true

Answer (score 0):

Above [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33769541/20141533) worked for me, but you need to add the load path to $: every time you open rails console.
Simple solution is:

- create ~/.irbrc if not exists.
- add these lines:

  ```
   $: << '/home/mehtab/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.2.0/gems/awesome_print-1.9.2/lib/'
   require "awesome_print"
   AwesomePrint.irb!
  ```

Now everytime you run `rails c` ~/.irbrc will be loaded.