# gem accessible in irb but not console/application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, irb

I've already looked at a similar question, but the answer isn't working for me: 
[Gem available in irb but not rails console](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4845010/gem-available-in-irb-but-not-rails-console)

I'm using the Gmail gem. https://github.com/nu7hatch/gmail

I can successfully call it and use it in irb, but when I try to do the same in my console, I get something like this:

```
NameError: uninitialized constant ApplicationController::Gmail
```

I have `gem 'gmail'` in my Gemfile. I've also tried with `gem 'gmail', :require => 'gmail'`.

This is the line of code that works in irb:

```
require 'gmail' # returns true
gmail = Gmail.connect("username", "password")
```

When I try to `require 'gmail'` in my rails console, it returns false.

Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: Did the `bundle install` work in your application directory? I would expect you'd see the gmail gem listed in that output and in your `Gemfile.lock` file.

Comment: What does your Gemfile.lock look like?

Comment: I see this in my Gemfile.lock:     gmail (0.4.0)
      gmail_xoauth (>= 0.3.0)
      mail (>= 2.2.1)
      mime (>= 0.1)
    gmail_xoauth (0.4.1)
      oauth (>= 0.3.6)

Comment: The weird thing is that I don't see any trace of the gmail gem in my gems directory

Comment: Are you using rbenv or rvm?

Comment: rvm - i'm having problems with both my server and rails console

Answer (score 0):

```
Gmail.new("username", "password") do |client|
  puts client.logged_in?
  puts client.inbox.count
  ...DO WHATEVER You want...
end
```

Try the above code snippet...