# How to get rubygems version in rails console?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

`gem env` or `gem --version` provides the rubygems version information, for example:

```
$ gem env
RubyGems Environment:
 - RUBYGEMS VERSION: 3.1.4
...

$ gem --version
3.1.4
```

Is it possible to get it in rails console?

Comment: I think you would need to `require "gem"` in the console first, but that is not possible, so you need to do this first: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4845010/gem-available-in-irb-but-not-rails-console then you can try `gem -v`

If you are running Rails 6, read the workaround in the comments

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Gem::VERSION` seems to work for me in the rails console.

```
> bundle exec rails c
irb(main):001:0> Gem::VERSION
=> "3.0.3"
```